# Passing length 0 string ('0') to STL functions that expect char*

Tags: c++, stl, stdstring

colleague(serioussly I dont use char* :) ) made a bug that reduces to this:

```
testVar.append('\0'); //testVar is std::string
```

So he basically this fixes it:

```
testVar.append("\0");
```

My question is why first one isnt legal?
 Cant it be considered as 0 length 0 terminated string? 
 I tried going into VS10 std lib implementation to see for myself but I regretted it. :)

Comment: The point is that '\0' being a 0 value char, can be interpreted also as null pointer for the special value of 0 respect to pointers.

So append('\0') calls append((const char*)0)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`'` creates a `char` literal, which is not the same as a string / `char *`. Some languages treat a single character as a length-1 string, but C++ defines a single character to be a primitive datatype while a string is an array of characters.

Comment: Moreover, in the first one the `'\0'` treats as `char` that equals `0` that can be treated as a null pointer on `const char *`.

Comment: @m0nhawk: True; I didn't realize that until you pointed it out.

Comment: @m0nhawk good point, it actually gets converted to char* :( now it is obvious. :) tnx, also the A is nice ofc.